# Identifying identical pairs across two columns

Tags: sql, database

I have a table of an airline company with Passenger identificator, their departing and arrival destinations.

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| PassengerID | Town_from | Town_to  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|           1 | London    | Valetta  |
|           1 | Valetta   | London   |
|           1 | Bangkok   | Hanoi    |
|           2 | Prague    | Vienna   |
|           2 | Vienna    | Prague   |
|           3 | Budapest  | Vilnius  |
|           4 | Moscow    | Helsinki |
|           4 | Helsinki  | Moscow   |
|           4 | Moscow    | Helsinki |
|           5 | Lyon      | Paris    |
|           5 | New York  | Toronto  |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

What I want to do is to find passengers who did just the one route there and back so the result should look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| PassengerID | Town_from | Town_to  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|           2 | Prague    | Vienna   |
|           2 | Vienna    | Prague   |
|           4 | Moscow    | Helsinki |
|           4 | Helsinki  | Moscow   |
|           4 | Moscow    | Helsinki |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Or like this:

```
+-------------+
| PassengerID |
+-------------+
|           2 |
|           4 |
+-------------+
```

Why this PassengerIDs:

1 - NO because there is 1 return trip and 1 non-return
2 - YES because there is just 1 pair
3 - NO because there is not a return trip (Bud - Vil but not Vil - Bud)
4 - YES because there is still 1 pair although more than 2 trips
5 - NO because there are no return trips to these pairs

I tried something like:

```
SELECT PassengerID FROM table
GROUP BY PassengerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT town_from) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT town_to) = 2
```

But that includes also totally diferent destinations (ID 5) to result set. I can't figure out how I can compare 2 columns while grouping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with SQL there are several ways to obtain the same result with different queries... I'll post mine.

Here's the working SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/385d3/1

Data setup

```
create table travel(PassengerID  varchar(64),Town_from  varchar(64),Town_to varchar(64));

insert into travel values('1','London','Valetta');
insert into travel values('1','Valetta','London');
insert into travel values('1','Bangkok','Hanoi');
insert into travel values('2','Prague','Vienna');
insert into travel values('2','Vienna','Prague');
insert into travel values('3','Budapest','Vilnius');
insert into travel values('4','Moscow','Helsinki');
insert into travel values('4','Helsinki','Moscow');
insert into travel values('4','Moscow','Helsinki');
```

And the actual query

```
SELECT DISTINCT PassengerID
FROM TRAVEL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT PassengerID 
  FROM TRAVEL a
  WHERE TRAVEL.PassengerID = a.PassengerID AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM TRAVEL b
    WHERE a.PassengerID = b.PassengerID 
    AND a.Town_from = b.Town_to
    AND a.Town_to = b.Town_from
))
```

The innermost query (`FROM TRAVEL b`) finds all return trips with respect to the intermediate query (`FROM TRAVEL a`).

The intermediate query (`FROM TRAVEL a`) then returns the PassengerID of all passengers in all trips that DO NOT have a return trip using `NOT EXISTS` clause.

The outer query inverts the result again, removing these "unmatched" trips from the initial table.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FlightData TABLE (
    PassengerID INT,
    Town_from NVARCHAR(500),
    Town_to NVARCHAR(500)
)
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 1,'London','Valetta'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 1,'Valetta','London'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 1,'Bangkok','Hanoi'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 2,'Prague','Vienna'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 2,'Vienna','Prague'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 3,'Budapest','Vilnius'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 4,'Moscow','Helsinki'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 4,'Helsinki','Moscow'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 4,'Moscow','Helsinki'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 5,'Lyon','Paris'
INSERT INTO @FlightData(PassengerID,Town_from,Town_to) SELECT 5,'New York','Toronto'

SELECT *
FROM @FlightData
WHERE PassengerID NOT IN(
    SELECT
        fd1.PassengerID
    FROM @FlightData fd1
    LEFT JOIN @FlightData fd2 ON fd2.PassengerID=fd1.PassengerID
        AND fd2.Town_from=fd1.Town_to
        AND fd2.Town_to=fd1.Town_from
    WHERE fd2.PassengerID IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data and explanation is ambiguous since you eliminate ID 1 because it has two different pairs (although one is a round trip and one isn't) but you eliminate ID 5 because there are no return trips to either of the one leg flights which indicates that ID 5 would be included if it had return trips but ID 1 would not if there was a Hanoi to Bangkok leg included.

Do you only include ID's that have a *single* from/to pair (but multiple trips are ok)?  This is not clear.

This is another example that will yield your desired results of ID 2 and 4 (however it does not include any ID's that would have multiple complete and different round trips if that was your intention)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) FROM Travel t1 JOIN Travel t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id AND 
t1.town_from=t2.town_to AND t1.town_from<>t2.town_from AND 
t1.town_to<>t2.town_to)
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) FROM Travel t1 JOIN Travel t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id AND 
t1.town_from<>t2.town_to AND t1.town_from<>t2.town_from AND 
t1.town_to<>t2.town_to)
```

The first query eliminates ID 3 (and the like) since it select only ID's that have at least one 'round trip'.  The second query finds all of the ID's that have non complete or different trips and eliminates them.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for that, I will update the question although it has been answered. 

The task I solve requires just ID's with a single from/to pairs even with multiple trips. I tried to simplify data for this question and forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
select distinct t1.PassengerID
from
    travel t1
    inner join travel t2
        on t1.PassengerID = t2.PassengerID AND
           t1.Town_from = t2.Town_to AND
           t1.Town_to = t2.Town_from
where
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PassengerID, Town_from, Town_to
           FROM travel t3
           WHERE t3.PassengerID = t1.PassengerID) temp
    ) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ed3a/4

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select distinct trv1.PassengerID, 
trv1.town_from AS a, 
trv1.town_to AS b, 
trv2.town_from AS c, 
trv2.town_to AS d  
FROM travel trv1
LEFT JOIN travel trv2 ON trv1.PassengerID=trv2.PassengerID
AND trv1.town_from=trv2.town_to
AND trv1.town_to=trv2.town_from
ORDER BY trv1.PassengerID, trv1.town_from
), 

SCTE AS
(
SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by CTE.PassengerID) AS count
FROM CTE
),

SSCTE AS
(
SELECT *, sum(SCTE.count) over(partition by SCTE.PassengerID) AS sum
FROM SCTE
)

SELECT 
SSCTE.PassengerID, 
SSCTE.a, 
SSCTE.b
from SSCTE
WHERE SSCTE.sum = 3
ORDER BY SSCTE.PassengerID;
```